# Can t access database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i followed the tutorial on :

http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

to use a database i already have written in sqlite but when i try to access the database itself to get the tables names the only one i get is: android_metadata.
I use a nexus 5 to do the testing not a virtual device.

if anyone could help it will be nice.Thanks.

Comment: Please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: Show us your SQLite code please

Answer (score -1):

Have you created more tables after following the tutorial?

In this artical it doesn't seems to create more tables than the one called android_metadata.

One option to check that is to try to copy the database file into your computer and then open with a SQLite editor (in windows I use SQlite Studio).

Regards,